# What's a color palette for blue, green, yellow, and red that is legible on both light and dark backgrounds?

Tags: color, text, hex, readability, palette

I'm developing a program that has both a dark and a light theme. I change the background, but there are color-coordinated labels that I don't want to change the color of.

At the moment I'm using the following. It's okay, but the blue, green, and yellow is a bit hard to read against the white/light gray background. (They will all appear on be on both row colors.)

[image]

[image]

```
Yellow: #FFD300, Red: #FF4C4C, Green: #3FB63F, Blue: #53ACE4
```

I could blindly play around with it until I found something marginally better, but I'd love to know if there was some graphic design standard I should be aware of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In particular for text editors, several colour schemes have been developed that could match your criteria. I am listing a few here that you could use as a starting point:

- [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized)
- [Tommorow Theme](https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme)

I am afraid I cannot say much more about them other than listing the colours and that they are designed to do exactly what you want.

Comment: That's a great idea! It's already starting to look a little better using the scheme you recommended:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Q5n.png

Comment: @crclayton: Did you also adapt the background colours? I would strongly recommend this, if it is an option for you.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that would be more far more trouble than its worth. I'm stuck with these backgrounds.